# How to execute queries from web users with different access to tables in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am running single spark context in a standalone machine. Can I run multiple spark contexts in standalone or yarn mode?

I have searched the web but did not find a concrete answer yet. I have come across job scheduling for a single spark application. But what if I want two different spark jobs to run at a time? That's why I need to understand if there is a possibility to run multiple spark contexts at a time. More precisely, my current use case is

> One spark application and two spark contexts

I am using PySpark 2.1.0.

Comment: since your apps are independent of each other, why don't you run them as two different spark apps?

Comment: thanks for your reply, but what if data sources are different but user is common.I mean as a user I want to see two datasets where some of its resources are common  but not all

Comment: Do you want _"two different spark jobs to run at a time"_ or _"run multiple spark contexts at a time"_? You can't have multiple SparkContexts in a single Spark application and hence my question. What do you really want to do?

Comment: Thanks, @JacekLaskowski for the reply.your site helped me to learn.currently, i wanted to run multiple spark context at a time .but you have mentioned that I can't run multiple SparkContexts in a single spark application. so could you please suggest me how could i approach to solve given situation "if I want to show two different data set/table to a common user where some of datasets resource are common but not all, think about a spark web app where a user logged in and he wants to see two data viewstable ". and also kindly explain me is it possible "two different spark jobs to run at a time"

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more about how to manage user permissions and has very little to do with Spark.

Hint: You could use database schemas per user, too to quickly differentiate between public vs private tables.

Let's imagine a situation where you want to serve two users: userA and userB.

1. userA wants to see a public table `publicTable`.

   ```
   spark.read.table("publicTable")
   ```

   Done.
2. Another user userB wants to see his own private table `privateTable`

   ```
   spark.read.table("privateTable")
   ```

   Done.

As you may have noticed there's **no** change in the code. That's on purpose given my thinking about the web app to decide when and how can access a table. It's not something Spark is concerned about (some may say there's a very little security you can find in Spark and that's because it's orthogonal to the features Spark offers).

You could also want to explore [SparkLauncher](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher) that offers interface to `spark-submit` where you can define `--proxy-user`:

```
--proxy-user NAME         User to impersonate when submitting the application.
                          This argument does not work with --principal / --keytab.
```

---

You could explore Kerberos that Spark *somewhat* supports that could give you much more sophisticated security. Since you use Hadoop YARN as the cluster manager for Spark applications that could be *the* solution.

---

Read up on the topic in the official documentation at [Spark Security](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html).